# Meteor #each block breaks #constant region

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a D3 donut that tweens so i require that the svg be preserved. I find the #constant region works like a charm until i try and use a #each block around it to make more than one donut:

As simply as possible (donuts here returning single item)

```
{{#with donuts}}
<div id="donut-container-{{emoticonName}}" class="donut-container">
{{#constant}}
    <img id="img-{{emoticonName}}" src="/images/emoticons/{{emoticonName}}.png"   class="emoticon">
    <svg id="svg-{{emoticonName}}" class="svg-donut"></svg>
{{/constant}}
</div>
{{/with}}
```

This works like a charm - tween behaves as svg is not re-rendered.

As soon as i do this however (donuts here returning [] with single item inside):

```
{{#each donuts}}
<div id="donut-container-{{emoticonName}}" class="donut-container">
{{#constant}}
    <img id="img-{{emoticonName}}" src="/images/emoticons/{{emoticonName}}.png"   class="emoticon">
    <svg id="svg-{{emoticonName}}" class="svg-donut"></svg>
{{/constant}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

The constant region no longer functions and things re-render instead of being preserved. Note in both cases here i'm still only rendering a single donut to isolate the issue to the #each block.

Any help with this would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So sometimes just the act of posing a question in a form clear enough for others to understand, makes the answer jump out...

```
{{#constant}}
{{#each donuts}}
<div id="donut-container-{{emoticonName}}" class="donut-container">  
    <img id="img-{{emoticonName}}" src="/images/emoticons/{{emoticonName}}.png"   class="emoticon">
    <svg id="svg-{{emoticonName}}" class="svg-donut"></svg>
</div>
{{/each}}
{{/constant}}
```

Seems so obvious i'm almost embarrassed :D

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the constant tags and run meteor with `meteor --release template-engine-preview-5.5`. This will allow you to use reactivity while still working with D3. Once Meteor UI is released (probably along with Meteor 1.0 in early 2014) you can run the app with just `meteor` again.

Comment: Ye, we tried that - while it did fix this issue, it did break some other things (that could well be more stuff we were doing wrong, but hey). I solved the issue myself though - see my answer